Dynamic numbers of datasets with facebook Hydra
I am currently working on a data science project where I can use different datasets, but on top of that I can use some of them in a dynamic manner (e.g I only use dataset1, or dataset1+dataset2, or dataset2+dataset3 etc).
Currently, I have one yaml file for each of these datasets (containing the necessary information to initialize those datasets in Pytorch). I'd like to be able to select one or several datasets from a parent config (e.g a train.yaml file).
The issue is that currently I am not sure how to do it with Hydra.
My config structure is as follow :
.
├── train.ymal
├── datasets
|   ├── all_datasets.yaml 
│   ├── dataset1.yaml
│   ├── dataset2.yaml
│   └── dataset3.yaml

So I thought I could do something like this in the train yaml file :
# train.yaml
defaults :
  - datasets: all_datasets


datasets :
  - ${datasets.dataset1}
  - ${datasets.dataset2}


But it does not work because I cannot a merge a DictConfig with a ListConfig.
THe only way I found was to use a nested defaults list, such as
# train.yaml
defaults :
  - datasets: 
    - datasets1
    - datasets2


But with this approach, since it is in the default list, I cannot override in a simple way it and anyway I'd like not to have it inside the defaults list if possible.
An ugly way would be to create a specific .yaml file for each possible dataset combination, but that would be impossible when I have e.g 10 datasets and anyway this is a problem Hydra is designed to solve normally...
Any advice ?

This is the recommended approach.
The pattern is described in the page Selecting multiple configs from a Config Group.
# train.yaml
defaults :
  - datasets: 
    - dataset1
    - dataset2
    - dataset3

You can override the defaults list from the command line (you need to specify a full replacement list. e.g. from the link page: $ python my_app.py 'datasets=[dataset1,dataset3]'

Ideally, I'd like it to be overridable from another yaml called "experiment.yaml" which will override every other configuration files (model, datamodule.... ).  Is it something possible or only doable from command line ?

Should be possible. Try following the pattern described here: https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/configuring_experiments/
